# How to map over union array type?

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have the following structure:

```
interface Test1 {
    number: number;
}
interface Test2 extends Test1 {
    text: string;
}

let test: Test1[] | Test2[] = [];
test.map(obj => {}); // does not work
```

I am getting the error:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ (this: [Test1, Test1, Test1, Test1, Test1], callbackfn: (this: void, value: Test1, index: nu...' has no compatible call signatures

How can I `map` over the test variable?

Comment: I have tried the different solutions that are mention here but is now working - can anyone help me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71113000/unable-to-call-an-item-parent-method-from-in-array-every-and-other-iteration-met

Answer (score 187, accepted):

**Edit for 4.2**

`map` has become callable now, but you still need an explicit type annotation on its argument to get it to work as expected (the type parameter is not contextually typed)

```
let test: Test1[] | Test2[] = [];
test.map((obj: Test1 | Test2) => {});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gIzIN4CwAUMqciAK4C2ARtAFznV1QDcxAvsaJLIiuiwAmZBAAekEABMMaTDnzEyySBMZYooAObsiXIsQA2EMCvmNBOANoBdZAB85w28gC8yW7shYAdFTgADgAUQQD2NABWFvK4jpZCAJRuAHz4HAmsQA)

This situation is likely to improve in future versions making this answer mostly obsolete (see [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42620) that will correctly synthesize contextual types for parameters)

**Original answer pre 4.2**

The problem is that for union types, members which are functions will also be typed as union types, so the type of `map` will be `(<U>(callbackfn: (value: Test1, index: number, array: Test1[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: Test2, index: number, array: Test2[]) => U)` Which as far as typescript is concerned is not callable.

You can either declare an array of the union of `Test1` and `Test2`

```
let test: (Test1 | Test2)[] = [];
test.map(obj => {});
```

Or you can use a type assertion when you make the call:

```
let test: Test1[] | Test2[] = [];
(test as Array<Test1|Test2>).map(o=> {});
```

Comment: Does `Array<Test1|Test2>` indicate the array might be filled with a combination of both types?  So it might be `[Test1, Test1, Test2, Test1, Test2, ...]`.  Where `(Test1 | Test2)[]` or `Test1[] | Test2[]` would be all `Test1` or all `Test2`?

Comment: @mtpultz `Array<Test1|Test2>` and `(Test1 | Test2)[]` are the same and indicate `[Test1, Test1, Test2, Test1, Test2, ...]`. `Test1[] | Test2[]` indicates all items will be `Test1` or all `Test2`

Comment: Is there a reason calling test.every() works while map doesn't?

Comment: @RanLottem since the original post TS has changed the way it allows such calls. Map is still not callable  because of the generic type parameter. every has no generic type parameter so TS can create a merged version of it that is callable. This is the relevat PR: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011

Comment: See [Improved behavior for calling union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) in TS3.3 as well as the [caveats](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#caveats) that explain why `map()` still doesn't work

Comment: Is there any fix for this problem in the future? putting type assertion create a dirty code when type names are long. there is a solution here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30271#issuecomment-476278582 . can we use it? It adds one function call for fixing this. is it okey?

Comment: Looks like [microsoft/TypeScript#42620](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42620) merged into TS4.3 has finally fixed this (at least if you use `--noImplicitAny`, which is weird)