# Typescript union types - Array forEach error

Tags: typescript, union-types

How to get around this typescript error

```
export interface State {
    ids: number[] | string[];
}
const state: State = {ids: []};
state.ids.forEach(s => { }); // error here!!!
```

One way is that i take Ids separately in a variable and cast it and then loop through that variable

```
const ids = <string[]>state.ids;
ids.forEach(s => { });
```

But this is not looking very neat.  Any way I can cast and loop in same line?
something like

```
state.ids.forEach<string[]>(s => { }) // not working
```

Comment: `(<string[]>state.ids).forEach(s => { });` would work as a one-liner

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks - somehow I was confused and was trying :(

<<string[]>state.ids>.forEach(s => { });

Thanks so much

Comment: `(state.ids as string[]).forEach(s => { });` should also work

Answer (score 0):

You will find [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10620) an interesting read. The issue is related to the inability to infer a common type between a union of arrays (in your case `number[]` and `string[]`). Since v3.3[enter link description here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#caveats), though, `forEach` can be called on a union of arrays, unless the `--noImplicitAny` flag is on (as the first arg of the callback will implicitly be typed as `any`).

So nowadays your issue can be solved without `as` casts, but still requires an explicit type annotation inside the callback:

```ts
type union = number[] | string[];

const i : union = [];
i.forEach((elem: number | string) => {
  //ok, do something
});
```

This is more faithful to your `State` type, as explicit casts are not safe. Having a union of arrays usually indicates that a generic would be more appropriate. Here is how you would change the interface to preserve the type-checking and avoid the initial problem altogether:

```ts
export interface State<I extends number | string>{
    ids: I[];
}
const state: State<string> = {ids: [1,2,3]}; //error

state.ids.forEach(s => { }); //ok if above is fixed
```

---

Also, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49511416/11407695) about the same problem applied to `map` method.