# This expression is not callable. Each member of the union type has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other

Tags: typescript

I'm getting this error on the .map function with the following code:

> This expression is not callable.
>     Each member of the union type '((callbackfn: (value: number, index: number, array: number[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | ((callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.

```
type ResponseTypeA = {
  data: number[];
}

type ResponseTypeB = {
  data: string[];
}

const response: ResponseTypeA | ResponseTypeB = {
  data: []
};

const data = response.data.map(t => {
  if (typeof t === 'number') return String(t);
  return t;
});
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this without using `any`?

Edit:

Here is a solution I found:

```
type ArrayElem<A> = A extends Array<infer Elem> ? Elem : never

export function elemT<T>(array: T): Array<ArrayElem<T>> {
  return array as any
}

type ResponseTypeA = {
  data: number[];
}

type ResponseTypeB = {
  data: string[];
}

const response: ResponseTypeA | ResponseTypeB = {
  data: []
};

const data = elemT(response.data).map(t => {
  if (typeof t === 'number') return String(t);
  return t;
});
```

Comment: `(response.data as (string | number)[]).map(...)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: How to map over union array type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510832/typescript-how-to-map-over-union-array-type)

Comment: Can you unmark as duplicate so I can post an answer? That link did not solve my issue.

Comment: In this instance I would suggest that actually TypeScript is pointing you in the right direction, and that you should be pulling the typeof check outside the map. Indeed, the 'problem' is that the type of data is (number[] | string[]), and the 'solution' is to cast it to (number | string)[]. Why not determine which case you are in prior to the map, not lose type information, and not redundantly check the typeof t every iteration.

Comment: "That link did not solve my issue".  Translating the answer there to this issue gives [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOYD2A7eEAq4IEEoF4oBvAWACgpKoATAQ2FoC4oUBXAWwCMIAnAbQC6AbnIBfcuVCRYCZGkzYAQgWLkqNekyjxgPAJYoA5oJFlxZcgGNUOqD1k2IzOIkdZIeAD4zX89xGVCUgoqOgZmQTFTKxtgOwc-AHckZiINcKgACjYuXihvHX0jAEpBKFEVe190U2s0OLDaDGTKhPRmpAA6Rs72WjBMuPwAPiypCCQAMygh-EIAIhzuHnniqAB+KABlXQNDQbXmYGKJMjrbRpVMqrl0bs0oWngspbyC3ZLBYt7+wYJR4LqPTTQbYKYzAhzKAAclePGha3swFYPBQ2w++2OpnUSJRaOAplExSEQA), both of which solve your issue as stated.  I'm not inclined to reopen.

Comment: If you think your solution is better, you might want to post it in the other question.