# .map() on union type of string[] | string[][] causes an error

Tags: typescript, union-types

```js
interface Props {
    data: string[] | string[][];
}

function Component({ data }: Props) {
    return data.map(v => v);
}
```

> map() throws an error: This expression is not callable. Each member of the union type '((callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | ((callbackfn: (value: string[], index: number, array: string[][]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.(2349)

Why is that and how can I fix it?

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOyDeAUMicgCZxhwBcyOYUoA5gNoC6yAPnQ8%20%20wG5CAX0KEYAVxAIwwDCGQBhDAFss8iOAAU%20cpTjJhtdNhwBKAsVJQIYCVAUUqAOhVwsWgG7IAvAD5kTzMhYSA)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510832/typescript-how-to-map-over-union-array-type

Answer (score 2):

That's a limitation of TypeScript. If you have a union of two arrays:

```
string[] | number[]
```

you can't call *any* method on it. You need to disjoin the union first.

**Solution one**

```
interface Props {
    data: string[] | string[][];
}

function isString(arg: any): arg is string {
    return typeof arg === 'string'
}

function isStringArray(arg: any): arg is string[] {
    return Array.isArray(arg) && arg.every(isString);
}

function Component({ data }: Props) {
    if (isStringArray(data)) {
        data.map(str => str)
    } else {
        data.map(strArr => strArr);
    }
}
```

**Solution two**

Try a generic version.

```
interface Props<T> {
    data: T[];
}

function Component<T extends string | string[]>({ data }: Props<T>) {
    return data.map(v => v);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty is that `Array<T>.map` has a union type, that is:

```js
function foo({ data }: Props) {
  // x has the type:
  // (<U>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | 
  // (<U>(callbackfn: (value: string[], index: number, array: string[][]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])
  let x = data.map;
}
```

This is a union of the *functions*, not a function with the parameters unioned.

If the definition was something like this:

```js
function otherMap<U>(
  data: string[] | string[][],
  callbackfn:
    (value: string | string[], index: number, array: string[] | string[][]) => U,
  thisArg ?: any
): U[] {
  // ...
}
```

You could use a type guard, or define a function that does exactly what you want instead of using `Array.map`.

The type guard option is as follows:

```js
function bar({ data }: Props) : string[] | string[][] {
  if (isMultiDimArray(data)) {
    return data.map(z => z);
  }

  return data.map(z => z);
}

function isMultiDimArray<T>(data: T[] | T[][]): data is T[][] {
  if (data.length == 0) return false;

  var firstItem = data[0];
  return Array.isArray(firstItem);
}
```