# Typescript : convert array union of ObjectId or string to an array of string

Tags: typescript

I have an array `foo` of the type:

```js
foo: ObjectId[] | string[];
```

I need to assign it to a string array `bar` as follows :

```
let bar : string[] = foo.map( (e) => e.toString())
```

This should be correct since both `ObjectID` and `string` types have `toString()` method defined. However the above code is not compiled because of the following error :

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '(<U>(callbackfn: (value: ObjectId, index: number, array: ObjectId[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

I am currently using the following workaround :

```
let bar : string[] = (foo as Array<string|ObjectID>).map( (e) => e.toString())
```

Is there some better way to cast the array of mixed type to string?

Comment: Playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2ASQCZQLxQN4C+AUBigDYCGATtMgPYB2AzsFAGZ10BcsiK6GANoBdKAB8oLKgEsGAcxEBuIvWas41HlNkLRuDnQB0AWwpgAPBQYgAfAApo2G1AiHgdAMrAZ8uwEo-RSA

Comment: @Terry this has nothing to do with ObjectID type. It has toString Method. The issue is with the union. Typescript afaik doesnt allow me to map over a union. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510832/typescript-how-to-map-over-union-array-type?rq=1

Comment: Why does the linked question not answer the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: How to map over union array type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510832/typescript-how-to-map-over-union-array-type)

Comment: Casting the array as Array<String| ObjectID> seems as a workaround to me. Ideally I would want an error if the array is not entirely of strings or not entirely of ObjectIDs

Comment: ^Alright, I see your concern. The work around isn't particularly nice. But you do still have type enforcement on the array _before_ you cast it, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Allowing foo.map()

It will work if you define `foo` with a signature that says "it's an array of strings and ObjectIds, and also it's an array of all ObjectIds or all strings".  This feels silly because the first part is implied by the second part, but typescript doesn't work that way.

```
foo: (ObjectId | string)[] & (ObjectId[] | string[]);
```

This is better than casting `as (ObjectId | string)[]` because we don't lose the information that the array has to be all of one type. But having the `(ObjectId | string)[]` included as part of the type means that it's ok to map.

You can make this into a utility type:

```
type ArrayOfEither<A, B> = (A | B)[] & (A[] | B[]);
```

#### Mapping foo Through a Function

If you can't change the type of `foo`, then you can do your mapping in a separate function which takes `foo` as an argument.

This works because the original signature `ObjectId[] | string[]` is very specific, but it's assignable to broader types like `ArrayOfEither<ObjectId[], string[]>` or just `Stringable[]`.

```
interface Stringable {
    toString(): string;
}

const myFunction = ( array: Stringable[] ): string[] => {
    return array.map(e => e.toString());
}

declare const foo: ObjectId[] | string[];

myFunction(foo); // no errors
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2ASQCZQLxQN4C+AUBigDYCGATtMgPYB2AzsFAGZ10BcUAFPElSYoAHygsqASwYBzAJQBtALpQAZHwEp0GZaPHAps5XIDcRes1ZxqPCdJm7cHOgDoAthTC9o2AHxQIF2A6AGUDe145UyIiUEgoAEEqKgoQGDYAUUlgAAsIKgAeBIAaKAAhf1xeBL0yxRV1at0xMuMzImlgfLYKZGgwwxkKODJoPCIoSahggYi5W3DZM2JzRhYoNxAAMQBXBlRJRhw+KGoUkB5Z2WHR3Xn9Qcd-camoGmAdqgZT5NT3T28OH8gRmixkkWiK1IyEoNCgFnWdDIGC2nB4miEOhUYjsRiU7U2u32wEODF4SJRnFMUAA9DSoAw6AFknQqEwYgjWIS9gdGAAmY5FAIADy6DAwTCgVyGIwgpTKIrFEqlYJuEF8vB+5x4SXO6SyuXyRXl-nuuIcKj8+AmU3en2+Zz+Hi8PmBQVCYIhyxi3OJpPJyNRdGpdIZTPyVFZTCAA)