# How to map over a List of Discriminate Unions in the presence of overloaded functions?

Tags: typescript, types

Given the following code:

```typescript
type Foo = {
    foo: number
}

type Bar = {
    bar: string
}

type FooOrBar = 
    | Foo
    | Bar

type FooOrBarList =
    | Foo[]
    | Bar[]

function processFooOrBar(x: Foo): Foo;
function processFooOrBar(x: Bar): Bar;
function processFooOrBar(x: FooOrBar): FooOrBar {
    return x
}

function processFooOrBarList(x: Foo[]): Foo[];
function processFooOrBarList(x: Bar[]): Bar[];
function processFooOrBarList(x: FooOrBarList): FooOrBarList {
    return x.map(processFooOrBar)
}
```

I get the following error on `x.map(processFooOrBar)`

> `This expression is not callable. Each member of the union type ' (<U>(callbackfn: (value: Foo, index: number, array: Foo[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])  | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: Bar, index: number, array: Bar[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])'  has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)`

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUBmCBcUAdgK4C2ARhAE7oC+66okUAQgIbXJqbYWeEAzsGoBLIgHN6jZtHhwA8tQ5cUvLAB9YCdVC0qZ4OQiUqAMqOHJdW+QG0AujbadHjHCSIBjYKLhEoMGo4LwhBQXlTTgAKAA9CeQBKBIQAbnQPb19-QODQ8MjlGPiXamTS9MyfPwCgkLCIkyLqOJTFZvLClR5sKGoIYBJqANjpDM9qnLr8xvbzS2BW7ThHToRHSons2ryGrs4LYSWVVcITh02smtz6gqb5o5L96kPgNbmDhZ7sfsHhqFiADoyOwwNFpnt7pxEvQgA)

I do understand what the error message tells me but I dont get why.

Is this a compiler bug (because the compiler should be able to unify those) or am I running against some hard limits concerning type theory?

Comment: Or option 3: It's neither a bug nor a theoretical issue, but rather a practical one. There are a number of places where TypeScript's type theory says X but it's impractical for the compiler to figure that out because either it would take too long (runtime), it would be fiendishly difficult to implement, or both. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems with the code above.

- The first is that `Array.map` is generic and can not call union types properly.
  The Problem is described here (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) and a possible solution here ([Typescript: How to map over union array type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510832/typescript-how-to-map-over-union-array-type))
  So the soution in the case above looks like this

  ```
  function processFooOrBarList(x: FooOrBarList): FooOrBarList {
      return (x as Array<Foo | Bar>).map(processFooOrBar)
  }
  ```
- However this is not enough as the inferred return type does not match the defined return type so we have to cast again.

  ```
  function processFooOrBarList(x: FooOrBarList): FooOrBarList {
      return (x as Array<Foo | Bar>).map(processFooOrBar) as FooBarList
  }
  ```
- There is still a problem now due to the presence of the overloaded `processFooOrBar` functions and the inability of the compiler to select the correct overload. So we need to give the compiler another hint via a cast.

  ```
  function processFooOrBarList(x: FooOrBarList): FooOrBarList {
      const f = processFooOrBar as (x: FooOrBar) => FooOrBar  
      return (x as Array<Foo | Bar>).map(y => f(y)) as FooOrBarList
  }
  ```

We do this by explictly selecting the correct function signature for the function `f` to be called by `Array.map`

- Finally I have set all params to `readonly` to prevent errors by changing the underlying array which due to the casting will not be found.

A full working example can be found here [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgewTAvDA3sG2YDMkBcMAdgK4C2ARlAE7AC+woksAQgIY2oZY6WdEAziBoBLYgHMGTcNHhIA8jQ5cUvbAB95CdTC0qZLbUpUAZUcNS6tNKOwAmCYgBsw2gNoBdazFsOnrjAqXky4pMQAxiCiTjAQNAgRUIKCiAgmnAAUAB5EaQCUeUgA3MBhkdGx8YnJqYrKWblBnIXNNKXlUTHEcQlJKWkZNDlF6Q00rYPjPDi+UCCkND3Z0mXhXVV9tVNmFiAjc-4ubmlek0heHeuVPdX9dWO7wgd+jsdtZ0TBnqWznTe9GoDepPfZNHacczCc6PSF7GazHARJyWXDcO7bEGcGDsQQwA4QiaoAB8xnGAEhdLNbAslvjsji8QBBGg0dhgAA8aT0bWJ+QAdOR2BBMm4UKTcKL8vlGWTQbpGMBnPM8Eg8Wh3OhVQgiABGGD0AA0GG1RAATAbvMqQID7lB7AB9fAIdW2zGwmhQ-bOwT5JUq-g0V2amCBogAIl14YNxq1YZg4bN0foVpVGJS9odgdd6YeQy9mWzfqAA%5D)

Comment: Maybe worth using two different strategies for mapping different arrays?