# How to use filter in TypeScript on different array types

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given is the function signature below:

```
function foo(): string[] | number[]
```

Why does TS complain about the follow function call of filter?

```
foo().filter((v) => true);
      ^^^^^^
      Error
```

> This expression is not callable.
> Each member of the union type '{ (predicate: (value: number, index: number, array: number[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[]; (predicate: (value: number, index: number, array: number[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): number[]; } | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.

Of course I can cast it to `[]`, but what is the proper way here? The error message is very difficult to understand? How would one decipher this?

Example: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=27#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKAXIsIC2ARgKYBOA2gLqIA+iAzlKTGAOZWIDeAUIn4qWJQQpJFQDc3AL7dZKdBgB0wGABsoZNGgBuGRAF4AfIiYhiGcUA)

Comment: The compiler cannot figure out how to call a method which is a union of overloaded and generic methods, as per [microsoft/TypeScript#36390](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36390). You could synthesize a type that represents what happens when you `filter()` a union of arrays, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wkv3Jm), but I don't know if you'd really want to use that instead of the relatively easy-to-write type assertion ("cast") as you said.  I'm happy to write up an answer unless you think I'm missing the point of your question.  Let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function foo(): (number|string)[]
```

For same reason as here:
[Typescript: How to map over union array type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510832/typescript-how-to-map-over-union-array-type)

Comment: But this is different. In my case I either return a string[] array OR number[], but your signature means it could contain mixed types

Comment: have you read the answer to the question linked?

Comment: I completely missed the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the first argument of the `.filter()` method is typed in TS to have the type of the items in the array. Since your function is basically "returning" `.filter((v: number)): number[] | filter((v: string)): string[]` the two signatures are incompatible.