# Typescript function param with interface object array & string array

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-eslint

I am trying to create a Typescript **function** that have a parameter with an interface of ***Object[]*** **or** ***string[]***.

```
interface NameObj {
    val: string
}
const myFunc = function(names : NameObj[] | string[], toFind: string) {
    return names.find(name => name.val === toFind || name === toFind );
}

const list = ['app', 'test', 'ben']

console.log(myFunc(list, 'ben'))
```

Lint Error [image: Lint Error]

but I am getting an Lint error in `find(name => ...)` of

> Parameter 'name' implicitly has an 'any' type.'

Typescript playground Link [Sample Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQC0gADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRonzFBTBPB3AERcwABS0%20mM9ysygc9wASmCKhwzQ8ZC8iHFzmB7BoXzcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiQ58D0Ii8fLpDKZgj5SWxfPADlQAHJhAA5SASPlBFQAeS%20ZHegmdWkgR1QjgUrmkeFATjNOmGWH0KAQiGhwkuNok4uiIgMHGxCyYrA4PCCGQUZGSDCWMYZkGT0gAVqAAN6KEolThj-JXVCUTjMRQAX2ljSpoEQeAAYlxYDycaf6o0lUvkMIV6PkBPJwBtAC6oAAPqv18x3zrZ3nBcZRoZIe24R8UF5W99ACZIMm4G8xx5AA%20foxwCGCeW5XlI2kFFIy-b8sJw3D8M4SMdQAbiAkoEVAJUwK4CCxwAucFw4ksc3xLwmJ4SDaNAHcd13SkaDdfdeRfSMGAIAhI34SMFCpBTQDwgi31E2V5UVJVDxPcwlQk1AdR1IA)

Comment: You need to narrow the type `(typeof name === 'string' ? name : name.val) === toFind` [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wgg99w)

Comment: You will need a type guards,  eg.  `'val ' in name ? name.val === tofind : name === tofind`

Comment: Your types do not have both the property val, that is why typescript assume it needs to be any.

Comment: What about this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510832/how-to-map-over-union-array-type

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that `names` might be either an array of `NameObj` (`NameObj[]`) or an array of `string`s (`string[]`), and while both provide a function `find`, `NameObj[].find` returns `NameObj | undefined` and `string[].find` returns `string | undefined`, so the compiler don't now which type to use.

The are different ways to handle this. I would prefer the use of generics. This way you tell the compiler that we can input either `NameObj[]` or `string`, and whichever it is, that's also the type returned.

```
const myFunc = function<T extends NameObj | string>(names : T[], toFind: string) {
    return names.find(name => typeof name === "object" ? name.val === toFind : name === toFind);
}
```

In the above code I also changed the function to `name => typeof name === "object" ? name.val === toFind : name === toFind` . With your previous implementation, you get an error since `name` might be a string and thus `name.val` is invalid. This checks the type first.